# What is the "center of gravity of a band"?

Tags: solid-state-physics

It seems there is a term called "center of gravity of a band" in solid state physics or chemistry which I'm confused about. Could anyone give a formal definition of the term or point to some reference that have a clear explanation of it's meaning?

Comment: Try *Fourier Transform Infrared Spectrometry* by P Griffiths.

Comment: Thanks, the term mentioned in this books is a "center of gravity" method for calculating the peak center. It's not directly what I'm confused though...

Comment: A second thought reminds me that it might be that the way they calculate the center of gravity of a spectrum is similar to that of an energy band in solid. But I hope there is a sure definition to the center of gravity of a band

Comment: From my cursory reading, it looks like the center of gravity is a method of finding an extremum and, in your context, is applied to the peak of a band.

Comment: It is possible since extremum ususally exists for a given band dispersion.